# Substitute {0}, {1} .. {n} in a template with given varargs

Tags: java, apache-flex, string

Consider a string template of the following format:

```
String template = "The credentials you provided were username '{0}' with password '{1}'";
```

Substitution variable fields are of the form {n}, where n is a zero based index.

This is the template format used in Adobe Flex, see [StringUtil.substitute(...)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/StringUtil.html#substitute%28%29). And also .NET, IIRC.

Since I want to re-use the templates used by the Flex code I'm looking for an Java equivalent. I'm aware of `String.format(...)` but the template structure is not identical.

**What is the best way to get the same "Flex compatible" template functionality in Java?**

Basically this is the desired end-result:

```
assert(StringUtil.substitute(template, "powerUser", "difficultPassword") == "The credentials you provided were username 'powerUser' with password 'difficultPassword'");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [MessageFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

You want java.text.MessageFormat http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html